# JQuery is running before media query updates elements

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to run a JQuery script when an image loads to fit it completely in it's container:

```js
// On load...
$(window).on('load', function(){        
    // Center images on card        
    $('.card-container').find('.card-img-s, .card-img-m, .card-img-l').each(function(){            
        centerImage(this);            
    });
    
    // Center images on card when window resized        
    $(window).resize(function(){            
        $('.card-container').find('.card-img-s, .card-img-m, .card-img-l').each(function(){                
            centerImage(this);                
        });            
    });        
});

// Center images on thumbnail
function centerImage(imageContainer){        
    let image = $(imageContainer).find('img')[0];
    
    // If image height/width > container height/width, set class with max-width
    
    if($(image).height() / $(image).width() > $(imageContainer).height() / $(imageContainer).width()){            
        $(imageContainer).addClass('img-v');
        $(imageContainer).removeClass('img-h');            
    }        
    // Otherwise, set class with max-height        
    else{            
        $(imageContainer).addClass('img-h');
        $(imageContainer).removeClass('img-v');            
    }        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works fine normally. But below a certain screen width, I have a media query that changes the width of the container from a fixed width to 100% of the screen, which changes the container's height/width ratio.

The problem is that the JQuery seems to be running before the media query updates the container width. It works as intended on resizing the window - it is only on load that the script seems to be using the wrong (old) ratio.

How can make sure my script runs after my page loads fully - media queries and all?

Comment: What is the width when Jquery runs before resizing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your code executes after all the files(css/scripts) are loaded

To achieve this, put your code within

```
$(function() {
 // code here
});
```

this doesn't mean that all your script should go inside the above function. you can use this function like this:

```
$(function() {
 init()
});
var init = function(){
  //your jquery code which needs to run after the files are loaded(media query action is performed) goes here
}
```